# Android : Implementing zooming in view paging

Tags: android, paging, android-viewpager, zooming, pinchzoom

I need to implement paging in android in which i also want to give pinching and double tap zooming and paging on clicking of next and previous buttons.

Now my problem is this if i use horizontal paging as given in the following project :

[horizontal paging project](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager)

i am able to implement zooming in  this but the functionality of arrow buttons is not working here.

And if i use view pager then i am unable to add zooming functionality in it, Can any one  help me over this?

Or Can anyone help me over how to add zooming functionality in view Pager.

Thanks & Regards.
Ekjyot